# How to import a class defined inside __init__.py in same package?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, import, python-import

I have a package like

```
package/
--__init__.py
--test.py
```

Lets assume class `Sample` defined inside `__init__.py` then how can I import the class `Sample` from `test.py`.

Comment: If it's defined in `__init__`, why import from `test`

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: I wanted to use `Sample` class as a parent class for class inside `test.py`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a relative import, `.` is package's root:

```
from . import Sample
```

Also, it is bad practice to include "real" code/logic in `__init__.py`. Most of the time, you should only `import` stuff within `__init__.py`, to make it externally importable from package level.

Answer (score 2):

Things defined in `__init__.py` become part of the package's namespace:

test.py:

```
import package
print(package.Sample)
```